# Ошибка "Grid index out of range"

Tags: delphi, база-данных, dbgrid

Имеется процедура многострочного вывода данных в ячейки стандартного DBGrid. При перемещении скролла выскакивает ошибка "Grid index out of range" и эта процедура не работает. Проблема возникает в этом месте DataSource.DataSet.RecNo. Если изменить размер самого DBGrid, то процедура работает прекрасно. Но мне это не подходит, так как данные будут со временем добавляться и увеличивать размер DBGrid считаю нерациональным.

```
procedure TForm1.DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
 LinesCount, StringHeight: Integer;
 ARect: TRect;
begin
  if Column.Width < TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.TextWidth(Column.Field.AsString) then
   begin
    LinesCount := TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.TextWidth(Column.Field.AsString) div
    Column.Width + 1;
    StringHeight := TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.TextHeight(Column.Field.AsString);
    HackGrid(TDBGrid(Sender)).RowHeights[TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.RecNo] := StringHeight * LinesCount + 4;
    ARect := Rect;
    InflateRect(ARect, -2, -2);
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    DrawText(TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Handle, 
    PChar(Column.Field.AsString), Length(Column.Field.AsString),
    ARect, DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK);
    TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.Next();
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Как получается, что вы на перерисовку каждой ячейки, вы изменяете высоту строки `RecNo`, при том что вы не сделали `DataSet.First` ни другим явным образом не обозначили соответствие строк грида со строками датасета?

Comment: @Krom а подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно сделать соответствие ?